# How to add extra property to existing array of mysql result

Tags: php, mysql

I am store the mysql select result by using the below method

```
 $getposts="select PD.PostID,PD.UserID,SUBSTR(PD.PostDescription,1,50) PostDescription,PD.PostTitle,UD.UserName,UD.ImagePath,UD.UserName,UD.CreateDate,UD.TimeZone from postdetails PD
  join userdetails UD on UD.UserID=PD.UserID";

$result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$getposts);
$rows = array();

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

From the above result I want to add some extra field like below

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

 $date = new DateTime($r[CreateDate]);
 $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($r[TimeZone]));

 //eg: $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('+04'));
 $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $rows[] = $r;
    $row.FormattedCreatedDate=$date;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: I've added an answer. Check if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) here. Try following code.

```
$getposts="select PD.PostID,PD.UserID,SUBSTR(PD.PostDescription,1,50) PostDescription,PD.PostTitle,UD.UserName,UD.ImagePath,UD.UserName,UD.CreateDate,UD.TimeZone from postdetails PD
join userdetails UD on UD.UserID=PD.UserID";

$result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$getposts);
$rows = array();

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $date = new DateTime($r[CreateDate]);
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($r[TimeZone]));

    //eg: $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('+04'));
    $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $rows[] = array_merge($r, array("FormattedCreatedDate"=>$date));//modify this one
    //$row =$date;//remove this line
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Using `array_merge`, you can combine the MySQL result and extra fields which you can pass in an array.

Answer (score 0):

I would key -> value it, to do that you will need to have the control of keys creation by having an autoincrement variable.

```
$i = 0;
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $date = new DateTime($r[CreateDate]);
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($r[TimeZone]));

    //eg: $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('+04'));
    $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $rows[$i] = $r;
    $rows[$i]['FormattedCreatedDate'] = $date;
    $i++;
}
```